# MYSQL- Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I keep receiving this error:
"Can't update table 'wp_posts' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger"

When Woocommerce inserts a record into the `WP_posts` table, I'd like the trigger to determine whether the new record being inserted has `post_title (column) = 'scheduled_subscription_end_of_prepaid_term' (field data)`. If it does, I'd like the trigger to extract an `ID` from `new.post_content` (column/data in new inserted row).

Once the ID is extracted, I'd like to update the ID. The ID is different than the ID of the new inserted row.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
delimiter //
create TRIGGER DB.Cancel
before INSERT ON DB.wp_posts FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE updateid bigint;
Declare variable longtext;
declare variable2 longtext;

IF NEW.post_title = 'scheduled_subscription_end_of_prepaid_term' then

set updateid := NEW.id;
set variable := RIGHT(new.post_content, LOCATE(":", new.post_content));
set variable2 :=  LEFT(variable, LOCATE("2052", variable)-2);

update db.wp_posts
set post_status="wc-cancelled"
where id=variable2 and post_status='wc-processing';

end if;
END//
```

Comment: The error message is clear, you can not update the same table where the trigger is getting executed.

Comment: What is the point of `set updateid := NEW.id;`?

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to alter the row you are inserting before it gets fully inserted, you only need to SET the NEW values, not run an UPDATE.

If you are trying to update one or more different rows in the same table as the trigger, that is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am, in fact, attempting to update another row. What are my options since this is not allowed? Can I call an SP from within the trigger that updates another row?

Comment: As far as I know, there are none other than doing it programmatically; which could be through: c#, php, etc code, or in a stored procedure (in which case any `INSERT`s to this table you want to behave this way sould be done through a procedure call rather than separate `INSERT` queries.